# add and delete div on button click with dynamically changing data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in angularjs...
I want to add and delete div on clicking add button and remove button and I made that. I have made my plunker

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/lzV2fjQFWmhQSB3P5Vzg?p=preview`
```

on click of preview I will hit the API and get myval. My problem is if I click on "add vehicle" I want a session with empty div(), so I can pass the value returns from the API. But for all the session always coming with the value that i passed in the first time.

I hope I convey my issue.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I don't get your problem, can you tell what you get returned and what you expect to be returned instead?

Comment: if you open the plunker and click on Review button "dd" is coming under the input box. and if you click on add vehicle that session also loading with "dd" insted of that I want blank div

Comment: When you click on "Review", `getdetail(vehicle.name, $index, vehicle.value)` get's called. And then you log `name+index` and `allVins`. I don't get anything 'under the review box'

Comment: What should this line do? `allVins.splice(index, 1, {"vin":name,"trim":value})` allVins contains a list of elements in the order you clicked 'review' not in the order they are sorted in the list. Maybe you just want to access `$scope.vehicles`?

Comment: if you click on Preview button one div will show with text "dd".. is not coming?<div id="myVal">{{myval}}</div>http://plnkr.co/edit/lzV2fjQFWmhQSB3P5Vzg?p=preview

Comment: `myval` doesn't appear in your code at all? Did you hit the save button in plunkr after changing things?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/FUcAcC?p=preview now I made it as public plunker. Hopefully it will come now. Sorry for the troble